# Excel: Count rows if more than one column is filled

Tags: excel

I have a problem with counting in excel. I need it to count the rows that have value in 2 or more columns.

My sheet is the following

| Name | Field A | Field B | Field C | Field D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Field A |  | Field C |  |
| AAB | Field A |  |  | Field D |
| AAC |  | Field B |  |  |
| AAD |  | Field B |  | Field D |

I need to count rows that have 2 or more values ​​filled within columns Field A, Field B, Field C, Field D

In the example the result should be 3

I have tried with COUNTIF and COUNTIFS  but I have not succeeded

How can I do this in Excel 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MMULT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(--(B2:E5<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:E5)^0))>=2))
```

Older versions of Excel may need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

or since it is only 4 columns we can do a boolean on each column inside a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((E2:E5<>"")+(D2:D5<>"")+(C2:C5<>"")+(B2:B5<>"")>=2))
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly (i use the second method), but I don't understand what the -- at the beginning of the SUMPRODUCT. what exactly is it used for?

Comment: `--` = double unary.  It effectively does `-1*-1*`  It turns the TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 respectively.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I Didn't know about it and it's quite useful. Thanks again